# how to create taskbar button w/o any window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have simple no-UI application that will be then converted to windows service. but for testing it would be useful to see when it's running. so I'd like to create a taskbar button as other applications with UI have. is it possible with reasonable effort?

Comment: Taskmgr.exe can show you the process, good enough for testing.

Comment: @Hans: but not for my customers

Comment: Your customers are testing your code?  Unusual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Buttons on the taskbar represent *windows*. You can't have a button without a window, and that window needs to be visible. (The window can have coordinates that place it off the screen(s), and it can have zero dimensions, but it needs to have the `WS_VISIBLE` style.)

Another option is to create a notification icon. It needs to have a window, too, but the window doesn't have to be visible. Getting that set up might be more effort than you want, though, if the end goal is for the program to be a service; services can't show notification icons or have windows.

Perhaps the easiest change is to simply make your program be a *console program*. Then the OS will create a console window for you. Your program doesn't have to create it or manage it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Object of type [ITaskbarList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774652%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), then invoke the method [AddTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774646%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on it. You don't need a visible window for this to work. A dummy, invisible window will do.
Of course such a window won't show up in the taskbar if you don't add it manually with the mentioned method above.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom window class and keep the window always minimized or always invisible (size of 0 and position somewhere near -32767)

Answer (score 0):

Windows services should have UI.  In fact, in Windows Vista and Windows 7 they are running in a different session and have no access to the desktop.

To monitor you service you need to write another application.   Usually such applications run with hidden windows and use the [notification area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330740%28VS.85%29.aspx) for interacting with the user.